# I dont know what to do with this PHP Code

Tags: php, error-handling, fatal-error, palindrome

The code below basically helps in finding out if a number is a `Palindromic Number` or not. Although I get my execution done with the output, I just can seem to handle all the "screams" and fatal errors that I get. How do I handle this. Just a beginner and trust you can explain in a way that I may be able to understand..

```
<?php

    for ($num = 1; $num <= 20; ++$num){

        $_array1 = str_split($num);
        //print_r($_array1);
        //echo "<br/>";

        $_array2 = array_reverse($_array1);
        //print_r($_array2);
        //echo "<br/>";

        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;

        while ($i < sizeof($_array1) && $j < sizeof($_array2)){
            if ($_array1[$i] == $_array2[$j]){
            ++$i;
            ++$j;
        }

        }

        if ($_array1[$i] == $_array2[$j]){
            echo "The number $num is a Palindrome Number";
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: SCREAM: Error suppression ignored for:

Comment: Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\wamp\www\PHP Projects Folder\palindrome_numbers.php on line 24

Comment: And which line is 24?

Comment: if ($_array1[$i] == $_array2[$j])

Comment: Some more I have found out using an online PHP Code tester. May be this will give a better understanding...

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution time of 3 seconds exceeded in <b>[...][...]</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
All of it says line number 24 plus the above error also comes.

Comment: your code is completely wrong from first line only and also it seems like you want to do something but asking something.

Comment: let me see, just one sec. reloading the code..

Comment: ok code reloaded. Please tell me where I have gone wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get to the size of elements, which is 1. However, if your `array` has only one element, which is the case for 1-digit numbers, then `sizeof($_array) === 1`. Which means that the biggest possible index you can use is 0. You need to change your code to something like this:

```
<?php

    for ($num = 1; $num <= 20; ++$num){

        $_array1 = str_split($num);
        //print_r($_array1);
        //echo "<br/>";

        $_array2 = array_reverse($_array1);
        //print_r($_array2);
        //echo "<br/>";

        $i = 0;
        $j = 0;

        $different = false;
        while ((!$different) && ($i < sizeof($_array1))){
            if ($_array1[$i] == $_array2[$j]){
            ++$i;
            ++$j;
        } else {
            $different = true;
        }

        }

        if (!$different){
            echo "The number $num is a Palindrome Number";
        }
    }

?>
```

But you are inversing the `array` without a need to do so and you are looping for unnecessarily long. I propose this `function` to determine whether an array is a palindrome:

```
function isPalindrome($input) {
    $size = count($input);
    for ($index = 0; $index < $size / 2; $index++) {
        if ($input[$index] != $input[$size - $index - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Note, that:

- the `function` assumes that the keys of the `array` are numbers
- the `function` uses a single `array`
- the size of the `array` is stored into a local variable to not calculate it repeatedly
- the cycle cycles until half of the `array`, since going beyond that is unnecessary, due to the symmetrical nature of the `!=` operator
- the `function` returns `false` when the first difference is found, to further optimize the checking
- if there were no differences, the `function` returns `true`, representing that the input is a palindrome

Comment: hey Lajos, thank you the code is working. Yup, I guess I was very close to the one that you have placed here. But I just need to know in order to understand, what do you mean by using $different = false? and what does it mea/its implications? Can you please explain,....

Comment: @SricharanKrishnan, off course. Your code failed where you tried to check whether the arrays are similar. The best way to do this is to search for the first difference. When you find it, you know it is not a palindrome. If you found no difference, then the arrays are similar, so it is a palindrome. $difference is false at the start, since there was no difference found yet. When we find the first difference, we set it to true. If after the loop it is still false, then the arrays are similar. If my answer solved the problem, you might consider accepting it :)

Comment: hey Lajos, this is really great. Thank you so much for your help. This is making sense. Yup sounds good and do pray for me that I become has good as you. Just hoping that things would turn out well for me! Have a nice day.